# One to many contact history

Tags: plugin, contact

I am wanting to add a history for the contacts component, essentially a history of them being contacted with a few other fields. I looked at seblod and it seems like a lot of overhead. I have written a basic fof2 component and before I dove in I was hoping to get a little feedback. I envision I can go to the contacts view and in each contact go a level deeper almost like the contact itself is a category for activity. I am beginning to move towards this being a plugin. Does this seem like a good idea and is this the right place to ask such a question?